# Fluid width of input element

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, stylesheet

I have a top bar (yellow) with **fixed position** and **width as 100%**. Within the bar, left `div` (red) could be any `width` (fluid). The right `div` (green) contains `input` element that:

1. Need to have width as the left over space in the top bar (meaning: **green area should cover all yellow area, regardless of the width of red**)
2. I don't want to add more html elements. So given this structure in code below, I try to use css.
3. I could use *js* to do this easily but I like to avoid it for now.

**Sample code**:
http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/jBQDB/2/

As you can see, right now I used `right: 0` for `.input input` and it doesn't work. There is still yellow space on the right. That means the `input` element width didn't expand out. I tried with `position: absolute` and it is still a mess.

Help is appreciate!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/jBQDB/3/

```css
.input {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.input input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    /* you want this if there's any border/padding on the input */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[Why does `overflow: hidden` help?](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats)

---

There are other ways to do it if you can't use `overflow: hidden` on the parent of your input, maybe the most common reason for that is requiring a `box-shadow` on `input:focus`, or similar.

Here's an example using `display: table-cell` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/jBQDB/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
display: table;
```

and

```
display: table-cell;
```

as it automatically resizes.

Revised Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/2VmFT/